# ReUp: Passing multiple pictures between forms in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I doing my school project and I can't get multiple pictures from form 1 passing to form 2. More specifically, on form 1, users will click on any pictures they liked and on the next form, the picture will slowly show. I've tried to research but for most of the topic outside, they can only pass an image. This is the code I try to put down on every pictureBox click event. This will run but showing error when I try to click on picture.

**Form1**

```
namespace CyberShop_Gia
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(textBox1.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You've to enter your name first");
            }
            else
            {
                panel1.Visible = false;
                panel2.Visible = true;
                button1.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox2.Visible = false;
            pictureBox3.Visible = false;
            PictureBox pb = pictureBox1 as PictureBox;
            Form2 f1 = new Form2(pb.Image, textBox1.Text);
            f1.Show();
        }

        private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
            pictureBox3.Visible = false;
            PictureBox pb1 = pictureBox2 as PictureBox;
            Form2 f2 = new Form2(pb1.Image, textBox1.Text);
            f2.Show();
        }

        private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox2.Visible = false;
            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
            PictureBox pb2 = pictureBox3 as PictureBox;
            Form2 f3 = new Form2(pb2.Image, textBox1.Text);
            f3.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(Image pic, string username)
    {
        label1.Text = "Welcome " + username; 
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.Image = pic;
    }
}
```

This is [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SECSq.png) when I tried to click on any picture on form 1, and the full detail of the error can be seen [here](https://textuploader.com/165yy). [Here](https://textuploader.com/165ix) is the full code of my program.

Comment: Nothing has changed in this question. The code you've shown works fine for me (aside from the fact that it never shows the hidden picture boxes after displaying one in a new form). Please provide code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: `PictureBox pb1 = pictureBox2 as PictureBox;`  **as** in this case is a soft fail and sets `pb1` to null if `pictureBox2` cannot be cast as a `PictureBox`.  Step through the code and make sure you are getting a value.

Comment: @RufusL  I have added the full lines of code you can see it [here](https://textuploader.com/165ix/).

Comment: @FelixCastor Yes, you right. But it didn't really fix the error I get when running the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning text to label1.Text before InitializeComponent(); do it after InitializeComponent();